# DoubleValidator allows to type point and comma symbols in TextInput

Tags: qt, validation, localization, qml, textinput

I have a strange behavior of DoubleValidator in TextInput. It allows to put both comma "," and point "." symbols when I type some float number. My current locale is "en_US" and apparently validator should restrict the possibility to type the comma symbol.

There is a simple piece of code where I can reproduce this behavior.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    TextInput {
        id: inputField
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        validator: DoubleValidator { bottom: -Infinity;
            top: Infinity;
            decimals: 4;
            notation: DoubleValidator.StandardNotation }
        text: "0"
    }
}
```

Later in code I'm trying to get number from this field

```
x = value ? Number.fromLocaleString(Qt.locale(), inputField.value)
```

And if I print the number with comma separator I reasonably get the warning

> Warning: QML Error: Error: Locale: Number.fromLocaleString(): Invalid format

and *x* holds an integer part of float number.

I would appreciate if you can help me to understand what I'm doing wrong. My only purpose here is to correctly validate numbers with floating point depending on users locale.

Comment: sounds like a bug. As a workaround you can use `RegularExpressionValidator` with `regularExpression: /^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: @folibis yes, it seems the only way how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior; the comma (`,`) in your case is a thousands separator

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).